# Request spec with Devise + Rspec2 + Spork/Guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, rspec2, guard, spork

I have setup Rspec2 + Spork + Guard + Devise

My files are as follows

```
#spec_helper.rb
Spork.prefork do
  #code
  Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each {|f| require f}
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller 
  end 
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  FactoryGirl.reload
  include ControllerMacros
end

#spec/support/controller_macros.rb
module ControllerMacros
    def login_user
      before(:each) do
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mapping[:user]
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        sign_in user
      end
    end
end

#spec/support/devise.rb
Spec.configure do |config|
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

in my request spec

```
#spec/features/documents_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Documents" do

  login_user

  describe "GET /documents" do
    it "should display document name as sameera CV" do
      #spec code
    end
  end
end
```

and when I run `bundle exec guard`, I get

```
  1) Documents GET /documents should display document name as sameera CV
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/support/controller_macros.rb:4:in `block in login_user'
```

So far I have done lots of fixes via google and nothing seems to be working, can someone help me :)

I'm on

- rails 3.2.9
- rspec 2.12.0
- devise 2.2.3

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mapping[:user]` to `request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mapping[:user]` in `spec/support/controller_macros.rb`

Comment: thanks for the reply, it didnt work, when I changed it, it says undefined local variable or method `request' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007ffae03aaab0>

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm answering my own question, and I was able to find a workaround for the question I asked.

Following are the steps I did

1) removed the `controller_macros.rb` and `devise.rb` from support directory

2) removed the `ControllerMacros` references from `spec_helper.rb`

3) Added the following code to

```
#spec/features/documents_spec.rb
before(:each) do
   user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   visit root_path
   fill_in 'user_email', :with => user.email
   fill_in 'user_password', :with => user.password
   click_button 'Sign in'
end
```

I'm sure there should be a more elegant way (as describe in devise wiki), but this WORKS :)